# new width of react component not respected by component next to it

Tags: css, reactjs

I am using this component: [react select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select).

This is my situation:

[screenshot](https://ibb.co/n6h7Zm)

When I add more and more tags in such a way that they don't fit inside the select component anymore - you can see position of other components (which are located next to react select) like the black "X" button are not updated, **e.g. the "X" component should move to the right since width of react-select has increased**. However, it doesn't. Can someone tell me what is wrong?

This is how those components (each row) is created:

```
<div style={{ display: "flex",  verticalAlign: "middle" }}>
    <Checkbox style={{ marginTop: 9, width: 40 }} checked={data.checked}
              onCheck={(e, value) => { this.updateTreeNodeCheckedById(data.id, value);}} />
    <Select value={data.value} simpleValue placeholder={data.label} multi
            style={{marginTop:"5px", width: "300px", maxWidth:"300px"}}       
            onChange={(value)=>{ this.updateTreeNodeValueById(data.id, value)}}
            options={[
                {value:0, label:"სატესტო1"},
                {value:1, label:"სატესტო2"},
                {value:2, label:"სატესტო3"},
                {value:3, label:"სატესტო4"}
            ]} /> 
    <IconButton onClick={() => { this.deleteTreeNode(data.id)}}>
        <ClearBtn />
    </IconButton>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried using CSS to hide the overflow and setting the white space setting to `pre`?

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi Sadly I am not very experienced with CSS can you give example what to write?

Comment: It's `overflow: hidden; white-space: pre;` but it's not that simple, you might have to play with the values and the attributes and it will depend on which element to apply these styles on. It would help alot if you could add a working code snippet of your work in the question so that we can debug and help you.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi Actually if I check the checkbox on the left then suddenly the width of all components on that row are correctly updated - does that give you a hint what is wrong? (its like if that select component gets focus then neighbors are also updated with position)

Comment: Hmmm that's even weirder as the `Checkbox` has nothing to do with the Select normally, that's why I think a working example would help alot with debugging, can you do that?

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi It is not only checkbox if I double click the react select component after adding items, e.g. it gets focused then again neighboring components correctly update position. That top div is just set as 'title' property of node of this tree: https://github.com/fritz-c/react-sortable-tree. that is the whole example.