# Issues with using react-selectsize component

Tags: css, reactjs

I am using [react-selectsize](https://github.com/furqanZafar/react-selectize) component.

From the image (on the right side) you can directly see that it seems it doesn't handle long tag names correctly:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgVpY.png)

(when I add tag with long name you can see the tag name is longer than the input box now).

Can anyone help how to fix this? (I submitted an issue but I think that component isn't maintained so unlikely I will get help from there).

Comment: You can use react-select by Jed Watson. https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select

Comment: @HarishSoni Thanks but I had similar issues with that too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47939566/new-width-of-react-component-not-respected-by-component-next-to-it. maybe you can help?

Comment: May be you are missing some CSS. If you can add some fiddle or snippet that would help me to help you. Since in my case it is working as expected

Comment: @HarishSoni really? which one is working correctly? react-selectsize? just add a new tag with a long name and you can easily reproduce behavior